# Best way to form submission without using form action in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile, cordova

I am building a PhoneGap application using JavaScript, HTML and jQuery Mobile.

All the HTML is in the same file, separated into `<div data-role="page">` as pages.

Several pages have a form including one or more text/selection input and a submit button.

The submit is not a traditional form submit button but a button which using onClick runs a JavaScript function which can do many things.

I want the form to have this features:

1. When pressing the button and after running the function, clear the form.
2. In some cases the function should change the page.
3. The enter button on one of the inputs should submit the form (Activate the function).

Should I use the form HTML tag? If so what should I use for action? How to clear the form?
etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can still use the form tag, as it's useful for markup.

Just make sure that your buttons have attribute

```
type="button"
```

otherwise the button will submit the form by default.

To reset the form:

```
function resetForm() {
    $('#form').each(function(){
            this.reset();
    });
}
```

Comment: How to reset the form? How to make the submit button the one to clicked when pressing enter in the form?

Comment: If you're going this route, you'll probably want to have several buttons, one for each function.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to bind onClick to an input type="submit" then you're gonna have a bad time.

Unfortunately even if you return false or e.preventDefault when clicking that button, the form still sends the submit trigger so once your onClick code is finished then it will submit.

Example:

```
<form action="woot.php" method="POST">
    <input type="submit" value="submit" onClick="alert('You clicked me! How could you?! It's cool the form will still go to woot.php. return FALSE wont help you either.'); return FALSE;">
</form>
```

What you probably want to do:

```
<form action="woot.php" method="POST">
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" onSubmit="alert('You aint goin nowhere!'); return FALSE;">
</form>
```

What you should do:

```
<form action="woot.php" method="POST">
    <input type="button" value="Button" onClick="alert('Away with you!'); window.location = 'http://www.google.com/';">
    <input type="button" value="Button" onClick="someCoolFunction();">
</form>
```

Comment: What is woot.php? why POST?

Comment: Sorry I'm a PHP web developer and woot.php would be the file that the form gets submitted to for data processing. POST is the method of transportation for the data to get to woot.php. I have never used phoneGap before but after taking a quick look at their site and product I've realized that the <form> tag might not be necessary. I'll comment back with a JSfiddle in a bit.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't use `type="button"`, especially if you want to have the best chance of the form submitting when the user presses `enter`.

Use your regular form `<input type="submit">` and then your JavaScript:

```
$('form').submit(function(e) {
  // all your form handling here;
  if (your_form_was_validated_and_handled) {
    $('input[type!="submit"]').val('');
  }
  e.preventDefault();
});
```

Generic fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: I misunderstood the question. I thought he didn't want the form to submit.